# Directory.Build.Props and Msbuild /nr parameter

Tags: msbuild

I have a quite huge solution and I need to add the /nr:false parameter to each build.I've found googling that starting from msbuild 3.5 it's possible to write a `Directory.Build.Props` and all the msbuild will realay to this one.

I've tried with this XMLbut doesn't seem to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
<MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE>1</MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Node reuse is a flag on msbuild itself, not in the projects. While environment variables are also treated as global properties in projects, some - like `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE` - are interpreted by msbuild itself, before even processing projects. So setting a property with the same name inside a project file will have no effect.

In MSBuild 15.6 (in preview at the time of writing), it will support a similar concept with files named `Directory.Build.rsp` which can contain additional command line switches, so you can create a file with that name and `/nr:false` as content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so till now I've to either add the /ns:false to each build project or to kill from task manager?

Comment: yes or set `MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE` as environment variable